# C++ self-enforcing a standard: size_t

Tags: c++, int, size-t

Simple question,
Would it be good for me to force myself to start using size_t (or unsigned longs?) in places where I would normally use ints when dealing with arrays or other large datastructures?

Say you have a vector pointer:

```
auto myVectorPtr = myVector;
```

Unknown to you, the size of this vector is larger than:

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

and you have a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myVectorPtr->size(); ++i)
```

wouldn't it be preferable to use

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < myVectorPtr->size(); ++i)
```

to avoid running into overflows?

I guess my question really is, are there any side effects of using size_t (or unsigned longs?) in arithmetic and other common operations. Is there anything I need to watch out for if I started using size_t (or unsigned longs?) instead of the classic int.

Comment: I believe size_t type is platform dependent.  Errors

Comment: @Steve, no errors, `size_t` is absolutely preferable to use for array indices instead of a signed integer. `unsigned long` is usually the type of size_t

Comment: Unless you have a suspiciously nefarious reason to do otherwise, anything that represents a *magnitude* should be using unsigned types. Which one is up to you, but it *must* be sufficient to contain all possible sizes, not just ones you *think* you'll never ascend beyond.

Comment: It's generally good practice to use the correct types. If that means `std::size_t` because that's what the function returns, then use `std::size_t`; the standard wouldn't return that if it was inappropriate. Do note that one way around the problem is not to use indices at all: `for (auto const& v : myVector) { ... }`

Comment: Vector is limited by max_size() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/max_size/

Comment: @amchacon which, you will note, is represented by `std::vector::size_type` and can be larger than the largest number representable by `int`.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < myVectorPtr->size(); ++i)` generates a warning if `size_t` is not `int`. It's good practice to use `-Wall` and `-Werror`, generally (or the equivalent for other compilers).

Comment: @vanza: Rather "because" instead of "if".

Comment: @self, you are right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`size_t` is certainly better than `int`. The safest thing to do would be to use the actual `size_type` of the container, e.g.:

```
for( typename decltype(*myVectorPtr)::size_type i = 0; i < myVectorPtr->size(); ++i )
```

Unfortunately `auto` cannot be used here because it would deduce its type from `0`, not from the `size()` call.

It reads a bit nicer to use iterator or range-based interfaces:

```
for (auto iter = begin(*myVectorPtr); iter != end(*myVectorPtr); ++iter)
```

or

```
for (auto &&item : *myVectorPtr)
```

Comment: With `vector`, its `size_type` cannot be larger than `size_t` so you could use `size_t`; however in theory other container types that do not have contiguous requirement (e.g. `deque`) could have a larger `size_type`.

Comment: That first block of code is a real mouth-full :P regardless, sometimes you need the size variable, `i`, to peform some arithmetic within the loop.
But in other occasions I agree the iterator way would be preferred.

Comment: Also, what is the name of the last for syntax? Looks like a foreach to me, but in C++ apparently foreach is [something different.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, what about for non stl containers such as an T* (generic array)?

Comment: If you mean a C-style array, use `size_t` there.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not sure about `vector`'s `size_type` must be `size_t` or smaller, due to the abomination otherwise known as `vector<bool>`.

Comment: @TC true, I guess my comment should only apply to non-specialized vectors.