# Iterator arithmetic type

Tags: c++

I see a lot of people resolve to signed `int`, but it seems to me like that is out of ignorance, because that causes signed/unsigned mismatches for container types who use unsigned `size_type`s.

Since there is no way to get the type of container for the provided iterators, I do not see a way to get the `size_type` of the assumed container to perform accurate arithmetic.

What type should we use when performing arithmetic operations on Iterators? Or even better yet, how could one get the underlying `size_type` of the container since iterators have no knowledge of their parent container?

Edit2:

What I mean by the underlying size type would be, for example:

```
std::vector<some_type>::size_type
```

for some iterator whose container type is `std::vector<some_type>`

Edit1:

I think C++17 is providing a solution to this problem via some container access functions:

These non-member functions provide a generic interface for containers, plain arrays, and std::initializer_list.

- (function) size (C++17) returns the size of a container or array
- (function) empty (C++17) checks whether the container is empty
- (function) data (C++17) obtains the pointer to the underlying array

More specifically size gives the declared type of the size field for the parent container.

Comment: As an example, the `RandomAccessIterator` defines operator `+=` and `+` which accepts a signed integer and returns an iterator. Why does this produce signed/unsigned mismatch warnings or a need to know the `size_type`?

Comment: Are you basically asking if you can get the `size_type` solely from the iterator? The answer is a big NO, think about an implementation that implements iterators as pointers, they have no information about the container whatsoever. The iterators "know" how to advance, so why would you need the underlying `size_type`?

Comment: Can you show an example where you've been given iterators and you need the `size_type` of the container? What if the iterators are pointers into a plain array?

Comment: @vsoftco because, it's like you said, iterators have no information about the container, and neither does the function I am writing.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera maybe you should post a minimal example and tell us what the issue may be. I think using a `size_t` in combination with `std::distance`/`std::next`/`std::advance` is safe enough most of the time. I cannot imagine a standard container that will use `int_8t` for its elements, so you won't overflow...

Comment: @vsoftco @Praetorian well, a sample could be as simple as `T mid = begin + std::distance(begin, end) / (size_type)2u;` where you may need 2 to be a myriad of potential types to prevent rollover from signed/unsigned integer division... In this case begin and end could be iterators to a container with who knows what size_type. It is bad practice to just assume the type  would be signed or unsigned or even integral or decimal. Therefore to be certain, you would need access to the `size_type`.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera I believe the standard defines the `size_type` to be the underlying allocator's `size_type`, which is defined to be an unsigned integer type. See **[17.6.3.5 Allocator requirements]** Table 28 from the standard.

Comment: @vsoftco, well the whole point of `size_type` is that it is implementation dependent. So yes it very well may be an unsigned integral for the default allocator but it could be anything for a different allocator. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755721/c-self-enforcing-a-standard-size-t) question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is to use `std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type` (`It` is iterator type), which is typically (but not mandated to be) `std::ptrdiff_t`. `std::ptrdiff_t` is an alias of a **signed type**.

I recommend this because of the following facts:

1. `std::distance` returns `std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type`.
2. `std::next` and `std::prev` takes `std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type` as parameter.
3. Arithmetic on bidirectional iterator may go backward.